# Why does my 2.5 TB HDD appear as a 2.2 TB HDD and a 300 GB HDD? How do I merge them?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I have a Western Digital 2.5 TB hard drive. (Model WD25EZRS) It's connected through an external USB dock to my iMac, running Mac OS X Mavericks.

In Disk Utility there are two volumes, totaling 2.5 TB but separate as 2.2 TB and 300 GB. How do I format / partition / group the volumes to use this was one large drive with one partition?

Adding [image http://mattmanuel.brace.io/diskutil_for_stackexchange.png](http://mattmanuel.brace.io/diskutil_for_stackexchange.png)

Comment: Do you need to preserve any data on either partition of the drive?

Comment: Nope. It's a brand new disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. It's the USB Docking station that I'm using. It has a limit of 2 TB for the drives that it supports.

[monoprice link](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=103&cp_id=10315&cs_id=1031502&p_id=8078&seq=1&format=2)

Answer (score 0):

Open Disk Utility (in `Application/Utilities`). Locate your harddrive on the left. Not one of the partitions, but the whole harddrive. Then click `Partition` in the tabs on the right (see screenshot). Then click on the the dropdown menu (where `Current` stands in the screenshot), and select 1 partition (see screenshot 2). Click apply, and wait. Then you have 1 volume.

**Note**, your data will go lost. Save it somewhere else. Then you can safely put it back, after it has become 1 volume.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I added a screenshot of my Disk Utility. Notice the bottom two drives are the same physical disk.

Comment: Okay. Than it isn't solvable this way indeed. I won't delete it though, as it will work 99% of the tjme